# Shared Variable w/Sub-Reports - Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

In my report, I have 3 sub-reports. I am attempting to create 3 different types of formulas in order to create a shared variable.

Formula 1: Transaction Type = 10

Formula 2: Minimum Transaction Number stored as a Variable

*Formula 3: Share formulas 1 and 2

*I have a Transaction Type that can show up under 2 different circumstances.

1. Transaction Type 10 upon the original Charge.
2. Transaction Type 10 upon an adjustment of the original Charge.

The second circumstance will NOT match the original Transaction Number.

How do I set this up so I can compare the original Transaction Number with the Minimum Transaction Number that I know that the correct Transaction Type of 10 will display? Not sure how to write this with 3 sub-reports.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: first question is what your 3 sub reports contain? what data are you displaying in sub reports?

Comment: Totals by Salesperson, Referral and Location. They use the same view but just breakdown the totals.